# Can I show different image on hover on products?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product, magento2.2, product-images

Can I show a different image when I hover on product image ?

Comment: Check https://shop.emiprotechnologies.com/product-image-flipper-for-magento-2.html extension. Maybe it'll fulfill your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can show different image on hover, using jquery or css. There could be 2 options either get thumbnail image to show on hover or create another attribute for image gallery and uplaod image there and call that attribute on lusting page :

Code to get image :

```
<?php
   $_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
   $_product = $block->getProduct();

   $productImageAttr = $_product->getCustomAttribute( 'product_image_hover' );
   $productImage = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image')
            ->init($_product, 'product_image_hover')
            ->setImageFile($productImageAttr->getValue());
?>
   <img src="<?php echo $productImage->getUrl() ?>" alt="" />
```

Comment: Hi naveed , Thank you for replying , But my client want to change it from admin side :(

Comment: "change from admin" means which image to show on front and which image on back ? to do so you can add an attribute "Media image type" and then add it is attribute set.. there you can upload image and get it on listing page template ..

Comment: how can I get them on category pages ?

Comment: i have updated code to get image , you have to create attribute with name "product_image_hover" or you can change as you want

Comment: Can you give me your email ?

Comment: @Learner, you can find in my profile

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75605/discussion-between-naveed-and-learner).

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code.

```
<?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
<?php echo ($iterator++ == 1) ? '<li class="item product product-item">' : '</li><li class="item product product-item">' ?>
<div class="product-item-info" data-container="product-grid">
    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" class="product photo product-item-photo" tabindex="-1">
        <span style="width:270px;" class="product-image-container">
            <span style="padding-bottom: 137%;" class="product-image-wrapper">
            <?php $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_product->getId());
                $images = $product->getMediaGalleryImages();
                $imgCNT = 1;
                foreach ($images as $child) {
                    if ($imgCNT == 1) {
                        $imgurl1 = $child->getUrl();
                    } elseif ($imgCNT == 2) {
                        $imgurl2 = $child->getUrl();
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }
                    $imgCNT++;
                }
                $imageUrl = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image')->init($_product, 'product_page_image_large')->keepAspectRatio(true)->keepFrame(false)->resize(270, 404)->getUrl(); ?>
                <img class="product-image-photo" src="<?php echo $imageUrl; ?>"
                     onmouseover="this.src='<?php echo ($imgurl2) ? $imgurl2 : $imageUrl ?>';"
                     onmouseout="this.src='<?php echo $imageUrl; ?>';"/>
                <div class="bl_black"></div>
            </span>
        </span>
    </a>
</div>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

You just need to change this code in 
*Magento_Catalog/templates/view/list.phtml*

I hope it will work for you

Comment: where to paste that code ?

Comment: @Learner paste that code on  `Magento_Catalog/templates/view/list.phtml`

Comment: @Learner Have you tried this solution.? Is this working for you.?